# iPad distribution question

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I just updated our app to an universal app for iPhone and iPad. I made all the changes (classes, nib, targeted device family, icons and so on) and it worked just fine on the simulator and my iPhone/iPad developer devices. I submitted the app to the app store and yesterday it got 'ready for sale'. The problem is that it shows just the iPhone Version and Screenshots in the app store and when I install the app on the iPad it just shows the iPhone version. 
I have no clue what I've could make wrong?

Does anyone know what it could be? Does it need a special certificate/provisiong profile or something else? I found nothing on google about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to check the "Release" target configuration of your build to check if the Target Device Family field (`TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY`) is set to iPhone/iPad.

Comment: argh ok thats it. I just changed the device family in the development profile.... :-/

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your Distribution configuration settings match your Release configuration settings for your Build Target, except for codesigning and verification, of course.